# How to bind 'tap' and 'doubletap' to the same element in Hammer.js?

Tags: javascript, cordova, hammer.js

I'm currently (trying) to create some basic elements for a mobile game I'm working on in eclipse using cordova. The main thing I want to do here is to set up two tap events on the same element. The code below shows how I've tried to solve this, but when I try to doubletap it won't get detected - all I get is two single taps. I've tried different things, but none of them helped.

I also get this alert in the console, when the double tap fails: "*Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed*".

```
var doubletapped = false,
    tapped = false;
$(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('blue');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap doubletap", function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'doubletap') {
            tapped = false;
            doubletapped = true;
            alert('doubleTap!');
            console.log('doubleTap!');
        }
        if (event.type == 'tap') {
            doubletapped = false;
            tapped = true;
            alert('single tap!');
            console.log('singleTap!');
        }
    });
});
```

As explained in this Hammer.js [changelog](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/243), I've set tap_always = false, but it didn't make a difference. What do you recommend? Is there any other library I could do the same thing without having this problem?

What I'm trying to achieve is to detect different taps or/and gestures on an element and then do different things. For example if single tap on element #1, then play audio file #1, and if double tap on same element, then play audio file #2.

Help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: have you tried only listening for the `doubletap` event to see if you can get that working?  Also, what about adjusting the `doubletap_interval` option - does that have any affect?

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
var hammer = new Hammer.Manager(element, {});

var singleTap = new Hammer.Tap({event: 'singletap' });
var doubleTap = new Hammer.Tap({event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 });

hammer.add([doubleTap, singleTap]);

doubleTap.recognizeWith(singleTap);

singleTap.requireFailure([doubleTap]);

hammer.on('singletap', function() { console.log('single tap!') });
hammer.on('doubletap', function() { console.log('double tap!') });
```

Comment: that does not work. only recognizes the double tap. even on a single tap.

EDIT: It DOES work. Chrome's "emulate touch screen" feature interferes.